# Samsung Smart TV Development Issue with Cookies being not persistent

Tags: javascript, cookies, samsung-smart-tv

Hi I am developing a Smart TV application for Samsung 2012 in JS and HTML.
I use this method to save cookies, saving and retrieving work great on emulator, the problem I have is on real device, where the cookies it is persistent only when exit and re-entering the application but not when switching off/on the TV.

Any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks

```
setCookie: function(c_name,value,milis)
{            
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + milis);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((milis==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applications on Samsung Smart TV is html files that loaded from local filesystem. They do not store cookies.

To store your values on TV you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) or [File API](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00001/index.html).